# Populating Realm Object Server

Tags: realm

I have an existing web application (Spring MVC/Hibernate/MySQL) and am writing a mobile app to cooperate with it.  The Realm Object Server looks like an interesting idea, but the documentation is rather sparse on how to initially populate it with data from an existing source.  The Java API is only for android.  So exactly how does one go about adding data from an existing source, ideally using some sort of supported API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is only possible to interact directly with the Realm on the server in the Enterprise Edition through the Node js API (and later Java). The Developer edition just provide synchronization between devices.

If you are using the Developer Edition, you can ship the initial data on the phone and put it into the Realm the first time the user registers himself. That would have the same effect as doing it on the server.

Comment: Or, if the data is shared across users, you can create a shared realm, populate it once from a local client app, and then access the data thereafter through `Realm.asyncOpen`.